# How to make visible of text boxes on selecting the drop down list which is multi select

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all i have gone through the example of dropdownlist with checkbox from here

http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=79

which works fine for me . But as per my requirement i will have 3 items in the drop down, if i select all i would like to enable all the 3 text boxes that are avalable on the form. If not i would like to make only the corresponding text box as visible

so in the script as for my testing i write as follows

```
<script language="javascript">
    function GetSelectedValue() {
        var chkBox = document.getElementById("<%=chkList.ClientID%>");
        var checkbox = chkBox.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var objTextBox = document.getElementById("<%=txtChkValue.ClientID%>");
        var obj1 = document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>");
        var counter = 0;
        objTextBox.value = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
            if (checkbox[i].checked) {

                var chkBoxText = checkbox[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("label");
                if (objTextBox.value == "") {
                    objTextBox.value = chkBoxText[0].innerHTML;
                    if (objTextBox.value = "hi") {

                       document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>").style.visibility = 'visible'; // This is what i tested but this is not working                        }

                }
                else {
                    objTextBox.value = objTextBox.value + ", " + chkBoxText[0].innerHTML;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So can any one help me please

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

**Change**

```
document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>").style.visibility = 'visible'; // This is what i tested but this is not working
```

**to**

```
$("#<%=txt1.ClientID%>").show();
```

I also recommend you refactor your JS function and pass in the ClientIDs and use jQuery selectors:

```
//note: I haven't tested all the selectors
function GetSelectedValue(chkList, txtChk, txt1) {
    var chkBox = $("#"+ chkList);
    var checkbox = chkBox.find("input");
    var objTextBox = $("#" + txt1);
    var obj1 =$("#" + txtChk);
    objTextBox.val("");
    $.each(checkbox, function(cbItem) {
        if (cbItem.checked) {
            var chkBoxText = cbItem.parent.find("label")[0];
            if (objTextBox.val() == "") {
                objTextBox.val(chkBoxText.html());
                if (objTextBox.val() == "hi") {
                   obj1.show();                      
                 }
            }
            else {
                objTextBox.val(objTextBox.val()+ ", " + chkBoxText.html());
            }
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Initially i set my control `visibility ` to false will this cause a problem

Comment: I recommend display:none and display:block.

Comment: then i should pass each and evry text box but i should display the text box visible as per described

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>").style.visibility = 'visible';` change this to
`document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>").style.visibility = '';` or 
`document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>").style.visibility = 'block';`

Comment: Initially i set my control visibility to false will this cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
    document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>").style.display = "none"
```

and

```
    document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>").style.display = "block"
```

Or since the example you've referenced has jQuery:

```
    $('<%=txt1.ClientID%>').hide();
```

or

```
    $('<%=txt1.ClientID%>').show();
```

Comment: Initially i set my control visibility to false will this cause a problem

Comment: That could be your issue. If you are using the .Visible = false property on a control in .NET, I think that the control does not render the input to the browser. (it's been a long while since I've used Web Forms). What you may want to do is put a wrapper tag around the inputs, like a DIV, give the DIV and ID, and hide/show the DIV based on the value of the dropdown. It requires a bit more work to manage the visibility of the container (div) but it should work for you.